# Column validation only when creating new item Sharepoint 2010

Tags: custom-list, column, validation

So I have a date field that needs to be a future date when the item is created.  The formula I have set up for that is:

```
=[Date Required]>TODAY()
```

This works well however I am running into an issue.  If the department is updating a List item after the Future Date it will still provide an error.  Is there a formula to use when the column validation can only be active when a new item is being created and not edited?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't validate at the column.  Validate on the whole item from the list settings menu, look for **Validate Settings**.  Set your validation

```
=[Date Required]>[Created]
```

Source-
https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-validate-a-due-date-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list/