# Validating dates in SharePoint so they cannot choose a date before today's date, how would I write that formula?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, validation, calculated-column-formula

I am back at this form I have people fill out in SharePoint Designer and have a new small issue, here is my formula:

```
=AND([Requested Posting Date]>=[Date of Request]+1,IF([Date of Request]="New",[Date of Request]>=TODAY(),TRUE))
```

If they choose today's date (The **Date of Request** field) they have to choose at least One (+1 day) (the **Requested Posting Date**) into the future and everything is working there, but they can choose a past date which is causing some issues.

How would I go about setting up the formula above that I am currently using to only allow you to choose today's date for the **Date of Request** field and nothing in the past? Let me know how I would set it up so they can't choose past dates with the formula above in a SharePoint form.

It is for people requesting work or tasks to be completed by me and I have two date pickers. I just need to know how to get the date pickers to not allow you to choose a past date, as if they were grayed out (the past dates, that is); how would I write that?

Comment: How do people fill out a form in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Is this right? `...IF([Date of Request]="New"...` I think your "Date of Request" field is supposed to be a date field, in which case it can't have a text value of "New".

Answer (score 3):

Add the Column validation to your date column as follows: [DateColumn] > Today() and set the custom error message. What is better than a screen shot!

[image]

Comment: Might this cause a problem if a user tries to edit this item next week?

Comment: the validation happens when you create or edit the column!

Comment: Wait, so if I create an item in the list today, set myDate to tomorrow, and save; and then if 2 days later I edit the same list item and change another field, but don't change the myDate field; you are telling me that the validation will not prevent me from saving at that time?

Comment: sorry the validation only happens when the item is created not edited!

Comment: I am 100% certain that is not correct. See for example http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175240/column-validation-only-when-creating-new-item-sharepoint-2010 - "So I have a date field that needs to be a future date when the item is created. The formula I have set up for that is:
`=[Date Required]>TODAY()`
This works well however I am running into an issue. If the department is updating a List item after the Future Date it will still provide an error."

Comment: Well, you can easily test it and find out. But this is the only way OOTB I know of to achieve that validation. You can do the validation using custom code, but this is a different approach. Let me know if you would like to discuss it

Comment: Column Validation **is** Column Validation and will always be executed, on New Forms, on Edit Forms, even if you change a Column with JSOM, CSOM, REST or PowerShell code (you can't update an Item if **any** Column Validation rule fails) So yes, using TODAY() in a Validation Rule has some side effects you most often do not want. That's why we usually add validation in JavaScript Code to the Forms [PreSaveAction] see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=presaveaction

Comment: How about referencing the Created date in the column validation formula or if not possible, in the list validation formula? Will that solve the problem? Just thinking.... Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to list settings -> Validation and add this formula.

`=[Due Date] > [Created]`

Even for new items the created date is set for today and when you edit the item you should be fine.

Keep in mind, the [Created] date includes the time.  In order for this to work when the condition is >=, the formula needs to remove the time:

=[Due Date] >= DATE(YEAR(Created), MONTH(Created), DAY(Created))

Using SharePoint 2016, Validation Rule

Comment: How would I connect something like that to this current formula I have, I have tried a bunch of different ways of trying to add what you all said but just get errors, please let me know what I would add to this formula here to not allow people to choose dates in the past on the Date of Request field, please let me know what I would add to this formula to allow that:    =AND([Requested Posting Date]>=[Date of Request]+1,IF([Date of Request]="New",[Date of Request]>=TODAY(),TRUE))           ?????    Thanks! ????

Comment: Replace TODAY() with [Created] and be sure you are specifying this validation in list settings, not in the column.