# How to customise date picker validation in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, web-part, jquery, validation, datepicker

In sharepoint, the date picker function has a limit such that if you pick a date beyond what the system gives, it produces the following error:

> "You must specify a valid date within the range of 01.01.1900 and 31.12.8900

I have items with no expiry dates. How do I customize the date picker validation in sharepoint such that **it has no date limit but it also cannot be left blank?**

I'm not sure if I should be using jquery. I came across this post which uses a formula to edit the validation: [Validating dates in SharePoint so they cannot choose a date before today's date, how would I write that formula?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/validating-dates-in-sharepoint-so-they-cannot-choose-a-date-before-todays-date) . If I'm supposed to use this method instead, what kind of formula should I use?

**Fyi**, my default datepicker in sharepoint contains a ms-formbody, which contains a formfield data-binded to the datepicker itself.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link....
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.fr/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html

```
=OR([Effective Date]=DATEVALUE("9/21/2015"),[Effective Date]=DATEVALUE("10/5/2015"),
```